# Is there a way to avoid downcasting or improve design?

Tags: design, c#

I have the following interfaces to allow me to generate "drawing" of some product.

```
public interface IProductDrawer
{
    public string Execute(ProductScope scope, ProductConfig config);
}

public interface IProductDrawer<in TConfig> : IProductDrawer where TConfig : ProductConfig
{
    public string Execute(ProductScope scope, TConfig config);
}
```

The first one, non-generic, is used in parts of code that deals with drawing universally,
without knowledge of any of the custom config types and drawer implementations.

The second one, generic, is used in parts of code that are aware of the custom config types and implementations and (it is a natural choice to use concrete types).

Now, here is one implementation:

```
public class WoodenBoardDrawer : IProductDrawer<WoodenBoardConfig>
{
    public string Execute(ProductScope scope, ProductConfig config)
    {
        return Execute(scope, (WoodenBoardConfig) config);
    }

    public string Execute(ProductScope scope, WoodenBoardConfig config)
    {
        // Code that actually draws the thing
    }
}
```

Now, see this downcast:

```
return Execute(scope, (WoodenBoardConfig) config);
```

Is this bad? Can I avoid it? Any suggestions on the change of the design?

Comment: Before downcast, I could check for correct type and throw exception. Any better ideas?

Comment: "I could check for correct type and throw exception" That's what a downcast already is

Comment: The design of an abstraction relies heavily on how it is expected to be used. You haven't provided much detail for that. Also, something somwhere must be able to match the right drawer with right config. That is something to focus on.

Comment: To expand on what Euphoric said, you have a design that is *covariant* in the argument type. On a purely type-theoretic level, such a design is never sound, even though it appears a lot in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

You could invert the relationship between the two interfaces like so:

```
// (Same as original)
public interface IProductDrawer<in TConfig> : where TConfig : ProductConfig
{
    public string Execute(ProductScope scope, TConfig config);
}

public interface IProductDrawer : IProductDrawer<UniversalProductConfig>
{
    public string Execute(ProductScope scope);
}
```

which leads to:

```
public class WoodenBoardDrawer : IProductDrawer<WoodenBoardConfig>
{
    public string Execute(ProductScope scope, WoodenBoardConfig config)
    {
        // Code that actually draws the thing
    }
}
```

and perhaps

```
public class UniversalProductDrawer : IProductDrawer
{
    public string Execute(ProductScope scope)
    {
        return Execute(scope, new UniversalProductConfig());
    }

    public string Execute(ProductScope scope, UniversalProductConfig)
    {
        // Code that actually draws the thing
    }
}
```

No casting is needed now.  Perhaps `IProductDrawer` does not even need its own simpler `Execute()` method, although that seems convenient.

Comment: I think this is the right track but can you give two interfaces the same name?  And for the more general one, is there a reason you can't just use `IProductDrawer<TConfig>`?

Comment: @JimmyJames As for the name, I just stuck with what was in the question but it should be fine, e.g. there are both IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T> in .NET.   The OP mentioned that they prefer to have both interfaces because in some situations they have no added context to supply a specific configuration. Though I agree with you it would be simpler without it.

Comment: Perfect thanks.  I'm not terribly familiar with C# so I wasn't sure that was legal or just a typo.

Comment: I think the difference with this approach is that you dont have a base class/interface for productdrawers anymore

Comment: @Ewan you could make a `class ProductDrawerBase<T> : IProductDrawer<T>` if it would be useful.

Comment: generics generate different classes when compiled. so you would have a usable  base class

Answer (score 0):

There are some equally ugly workarounds, but generally speaking No.

This is assuming you are calling the productdrawers from some collection ie

```
foreach(var p in products()
{
   var drawer = productDrawers[typeof(p)]
   drawer.execute(p.config);
}
```

the products, drawers and configs are always going to be in their base class, because that's how you can put them in a collection together.

If you want the method to be correctly selected by type, then you have to put the draw method on the type. ie

```
public class WoodenBoard : IDrawable
{
   public void Draw(ProductScope scope) {...}
}
```

Once you do that you can inject your drawer specifically for each type and you are good.

```
public class WoodenBoard
{
   IProductDrawer<WoodenBoard> drawer;
   WoodenBoardConfig config;
   public void Draw(ProductScope scope) {
      this.drawer.Execute(scope, this.config)
   }
}

List<IDrawable> products
foreach(var p in products)
{
    p.Draw()
}
```